# DDNS client for Windows

Tags: windows, bind, ddns

I need to manually update BIND DNS from a Windows server. The network team has given my IP address permissions to write to DNS. I'm having trouble finding a good client. I see that nsupdate is a good client for Linux. Searching for "nsupdate for Windows" has a lot of hits, but the clients seem less than ideal and require copying lots of DLLs around.

Ideally I'd like something using the .NET, Windows API, or PowerShell to update BIND DNS. Is there a good client for doing this?

To be more clear, I'm trying to take a cluster's hostname and manually change its IP address to be on different subnets. This will be used in manual failover scenarios.

Comment: Your question lacks some details. What do you mean that you need to update a BIND DNS server from a Windows server? The Windows DNS client is a dynamic DNS client. Are you talking about a Windows client updating its' own A record or are you talking about a Windows DNS server updating a zone on a BIND DNS server?

Comment: I'm asking for the former, "a Windows client updating its' own A record". How do I issue a command to the Windows DNS client to update a DNS record?

Comment: ipconfig /registerdns

Comment: sorry, was just updating my comment to say that I need to take a virtual ip and move it around between different subnets. The reason I need to do that is because I'm looking for a manual workaround to this problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40915/how-do-i-change-sql-server-2012-availability-group-dns-subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISC makes a binary distribution of BIND for Windows.  The installer has a "tools only" option which doesn't install the server.

I haven't checked, but I *presume* nsupdate is one of the tools; you'd also get dig, which is very handy for DNS troubleshooting.

Comment: Indeed, nsupdate.exe is included with the zip file that you download to install the server.